# How to load JSON with HTML Plugin?

Tags: json, templates, jsonplugin

There was a plugin I used with loading contents of a JSON object into HTML. One of them was called [jquery.loadJSON(jsondata)](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-load-json/) written by Jovan Popovic. The last version is 2011.

It has worked well but I've noticed that it does not populate the select drop downs.

If not this plugin can anyone recommend a similar plugin that loads and binds the json to the html objects?

One I studied is called [JSON2HTML](http://json2html.com) but this is a dynamic content loader which I do not want.

Another one was called JQuery templating but it looks like the project was abandoned?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most popular solutions for templating are [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/) and [Mustache.js](http://mustache.github.com/) (the former being an extension of the latter). [Swig](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig) is also pretty popular. For a somewhat different templating style, you can go for the ERB-style [underscore templates](http://underscorejs.org/).

Note: as of now, templating libraries rather work with placeholder tags, eg. `{{data}}`, than by associating content with `id, class, name`. The templating libraries I mentioned also allow you to put loops and conditionals among others, in your HTML.

For a full list on the better Javascript templating engines, check out [JSDB.io](http://www.jsdb.io/application-tools/templating/).

Comment: Thanks so much for the info but it appears that loadJSON() does not work too well with certain plugins when they have other plugins attached to the html object. I was hoping to find a template plugin that works with "name" of each html object.